# forvalues with two indexes

Tags: loops, for-loop, stata

I would like to loop over two different values in Stata, a firm identifier and  a year variable, and perform a regression for each combination.
The code should look something like this.

```
    gen unexplained = .
    forvalues j = 1/16 {
       forvalues t = 2010/2016 {
       quietly reg y x if firm_id == `j' & year == `t', nocon
       predict error, residuals
       quietly replace unexplained = error if firm_id == `j' & year == `t'
       drop error
       }
    }
```

Hence there should be 16 x 6 = 96 separate regressions.

Unfortunately, I get a

```
no observations 
r(2000)
```

error message. I know that that I am indexing wrongly.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `statsby`.

Comment: There are several possible causes of that error. Is the error coming from the first regression? Are `y` and `x` numeric? What about the grouping variables? Also, you should get `16 * 7` regressions.

Comment: `statsby` won't help with residuals calculation.

Comment: Dear @YDavis, you're of course right. There are `16 x 7` regressions. 
The rest was resolved by Mr. Cox' solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer is to check how many observations are available for each regression and to `regress` only if you have enough for the regression to be worthwhile.  Choose a small number at your peril.

```
gen unexplained = .

quietly forvalues j = 1/16 {
    forvalues t = 2010/2016 {
        count if !missing(y, x) & firm_id == `j' & year == `t'
        if r(N) >= 7 { 
            reg y x if firm_id == `j' & year == `t', nocon
            predict error, residuals
            replace unexplained = error if firm_id == `j' & year == `t'
            drop error
        }
    }
}
```

A variable containing the counts may also be useful:

```
bysort firm_id year: egen available_n = total(!missing(y, x))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Cox. I wasn't aware of the fact that there might not be enough observations. The solution works really fine.